# Constraint of cvxpy: How to constrain only some elements of the variable to be nonzero?

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I have a variable made of 961 elements. And I have a constraint like this: only 8 elements of the variable are nonzero, and the others are 0. I don't know how to express this constraint in cvxpy. I tried this:

```py
import cvxpy as cp
K = cp.Variable(961, integer=Ture)    
s = 0    
constraint = [cp.sum([s+1 for t in K if t!=0])==8]
```

But I got the following error:

> Exception: Cannot evaluate the truth value of a constraint or chain constraints, e.g., 1 >= x >= 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at this mathematically.

Problem: You have integer variables `x[i] ∈ {0,1,2,...,N}` and you want to allow only K of them to be nonzero.

We can do this by introducing a parallel **binary** variable `b[i] ∈ {0,1}` that indicates whether `x[i]` is pinned to zero. I use the convention:

```
  b[i] = 0 => x[i] = 0
  b[i] = 1 => x[i] ∈ {0,1,2,...,N}
```

This can be written simply as a set of constraints:

```
  x[i] <= N*b[i]
  sum(i,b[i]) = K
```

If you want to use the slightly different definition:

```
  b[i] = 0 => x[i] = 0
  b[i] = 1 => x[i] ∈ {1,2,...,N}
```

then we need:

```
  x[i] <= N*b[i]
  x[i] >= b[i]
  sum(i,b[i]) = K
```

If the integer variables are: `x[i] ∈ {-N,...,-2,-1,0,1,2,...,N}` then we can do:

```
  x[i] <= N*b[i]
  x[i] >= -N*b[i]
  sum(i,b[i]) = K
```

I assume that CVXPY generates the same thing when you say:

```
  abs(x) <= N*b
  sum(b) == K
```

(The condition `abs(x[i]) >= b[i]` is a little bit more messy to linearize in this case).

This should not be too difficult to transcribe into a CVXPY model. Note that we need this explicit upper bound N on `x[i]`. Make it not too large.

Comment: The variable x includes some negative elements, I tried `constraint=[cp.abs(x)<=1500*b, cp.sum(b)==8]`, is it OK? @Erwin Kalvelagen

Comment: Yes, that looks ok. We can also the linearization ourselves (I added that to the answer).